# Creating custom apt and yum repository

Tags: yum, apt

I need to set up a local repository to maintain custom rpms and deb packages.
The use case is to make sure that any client machine in my setup should first try to fetch package from the official mirrors but in case the package is not maintained then should try out in the local repository.

Is there any way we can mimic yum/apt repos locally such that they are always in sync with the official repository but can also maintain custom rpms/debs.

Comment: Can you more clearly state what part of this you are trying to do? Creating a local yum repository is very simple (I don't know about an apt repository but I imagine it isn't overly complicated). Are you asking about what you need to do to do that? Are you asking how to have a local mirror of an upstream repository? Are you asking how to merge those two things?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply.

Comment: The way I see this is to  use utility createrepo on redhat to create a custom repository and use reporepro to create custom apt repository on Ubuntu . Both these utilities would take care of generating the required metadata/headers for the custom packages in the custom repository. This should be followed by configuring the client nodes which access this repository using the appropriate conf files (yum.conf and sources.list.d). I am trying to look at is how create a unified repository for both rpms and debs without caring about the OS of the host serving these pkgs

Comment: The host OS doesn't matter for a yum repo (and I can't imagine it does for an apt repo). The tool that creates the metadata matters. But I believe createrepo is packaged for debian/etc. and reprepo/etc. might be packaged for Fedora/etc. as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check out OpenRepo: https://github.com/openkilt/openrepo

This is an open source package hosting server that can make packages available for both Debian (APT) and Red Hat (RPM) files.

You could use the CLI program to auto-update the repo.  For example, on a cron job check the public repos for changes, and if found, push the new packages to OpenRepo